# DOCTYPE for html Layers

Tags: html, stack, layer

i have my doctype set as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

but this is not rendering z-indexed layers at all.

i tried `<!doctype html>` and it still does not work.

so my question is in order for stacked layers to work which doctype should i declare?

thank you for your help.

EDIT: i think stack layering is not a part of HTML any more, from web searchs i gather. how do i go about placing an image on top of another image then? thanks!

EDIT: it is dependant on which version of doctype being used. the layering works in compability mode but not in normal mode.

Comment: provide more code, it shouldn't be dependent on HTML but CSS version/doctype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the hell are you talking about there.

For `z-index` to work, element must be positioned either as `absolute` or `relative`. And it has nothing to do with doctypes.

Comment: well the examples i found on the web are not working, only in compatibility mode. any ideas as to why?

Comment: http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp if you look at this you will see what i mean. but.... it works in firefox, chrome! im confused.

Comment: @iGuygar http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp  << is that your code which does not work ? If not , then show your code.

Comment: i am investigating will get back soon.